# Can I specify a schema when reading/writing a Parquet file using Polars in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, rust, schema, python-polars

When reading a CSV file using Polars in Python, we can use the parameter `dtypes` to specify the schema to use (for some columns). I wonder can we do the same when reading or writing a Parquet file? I tried to specify the `dtypes` parameter but it doesn't work.

I have some Parquet files generated from PySpark and want to load those Parquet files into Rust. The Rust requires unsigned integers while Spark/PySpark does not have unsigned integers and output signed integers into Parquet files. To make things simpler, I'd like to convert types of columns of Parquet files before loading them into Rust. I know there are several different ways to achieve this (both in pandas and polars) but I wonder whether there's easy and efficient way to do this using polars.

The code that I used to cast column types using polars in Python is as below.

```
import polars as pl

...
df["id0"] = df.id0.cast(pl.datatypes.UInt64)
```

Comment: please add [`MWE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) what you have done so far

Answer (score 4):

Parquet files have a schema. We respect the schema of:

- the parquet file upon reading
- the `DataFrame` upon writing

If you want to change the schema you read/write, you need to cast columns in the `DataFrame`.

That's what we would do if we would accept a schema, so efficiency is the same.

Comment: I understand that in Rust we can do this efficiently as we can use a mutable reference in Rust. But would you elaborate a little bit more how you would cast column types in Python? The approach that I used was `df["id0"] = df.id0.cast(pl.datatypes.UInt64)` as `Series.cast` is not in-place. This does not seem to be an efficient way to me.

Comment: Also in rust we cannot do it in place. The arrow arrays are behind an `Arc`. And if it weren't you'd still want another buffer as you want to cast datatypes which may have different layouts.